# Merge two table based on row name

Tags: r

I need to merge two table into one based on Row name, each table has 172 rows and 172 columns example of my data look

```
#table 1 
A B C
1 2 3
2 3 4
5 6 7

#table 2
A B C
1 3 8
2 4 6
5 4 2
```

I want my output like this

```
A B C
1 2 3
1 3 8
2 3 4
2 4 6
5 6 7
5 4 2
```

Comment: try `mapply(rbind, table1, table2)`

Comment: Thanks you. it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(rbind, table1, table2)
```

This function is fine for your case. However, if the table that you have is like this:

```
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 5 6 7

  A B C
1 5 4 2
2 2 4 6
3 1 3 8
```

The function above will result in:

```
     A B C
[1,] 1 2 3
[2,] 5 4 2
[3,] 2 3 4
[4,] 2 4 6
[5,] 5 6 7
[6,] 1 3 8
```

So if you want to get the result that you want, you can use this function:

```
rbind(table1,table2)[order(rbind(table1,table2)$A),]
```

Answer (score 0):

rbind is the function you are looking for.

```
rbind(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapply`,

```
mapply(rbind, table1, table2)

#     A B C
#[1,] 1 2 3
#[2,] 1 3 8
#[3,] 2 3 4
#[4,] 2 4 6
#[5,] 5 6 7
#[6,] 5 4 2
```

Comment: now can we do the same for column. i used mapply(cbind,table1,table2) but it not adding to neighboring column

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbind` with `order`

```
rbind(table1, table2)[order(c(seq_len(nrow(table1)), seq_len(nrow(table2)))),]
#   A B C
#1 1 2 3
#4 1 3 8
#2 2 3 4
#5 2 4 6
#3 5 6 7
#6 5 4 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `rbind(table1, table2)`